# Exclude directories by missing file with Symfony Finder

Tags: php, symfony, finder, symfony-finder

Is there a way to exclude folders missing some files?

E.g. I have folders like:

```
FolderA
    aaa.php
    bbb.php
    ccc.php

FolderB
    aaa.php
    bbb.php
    ccc.php

FolderC
    aaa.php

FolderD
    aaa.php
    bbb.php
    ccc.php
```

I only want to have `FolderA`, `FolderB` and `FolderD` (or exclude `FolderC`) because `FolderC` does not have all expected files.

Current Source

```
$dirs   = [];
$finder = new Finder();
$finder->directories()->in(__DIR__)->depth('== 0');
foreach ($finder as $directory){
        $dirs [] = $directory->getRelativePathname();
}
print_r($dirs);
```

Current Output:

```
array(
    [0] => FolderA
    [1] => FolderB
    [2] => FolderC
    [3] => FolderD
)
```

Answer (score 1):

A naive approach:

```
<?php

require_once(__DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php');

use Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder;

$dirs   = [];
$finder = new Finder();
$finder->directories()->in(__DIR__)->depth('== 0');

$requiredFiles = ['aaa.php', 'bbb.php', 'ccc.php'];

foreach ($finder as $directory) {
    $fullPath = $directory->getPathname();

    // if one file is not in this directory, ignore this directory
    foreach ($requiredFiles as $requiredFile) {
        if (!file_exists($fullPath.'/'.$requiredFile)) {
            continue 2;
        }
    }

    $dirs[] = $directory->getRelativePathname();
}

print_r($dirs);
```

It will output this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => FolderD
    [1] => FolderB
    [2] => FolderA
)
```

If you want folders to be ordered, simply call `sort($dirs);` after the `foreach` block.

Comment: This more kind of a workaround. But a possibility :) I still would prefer a `finder` way :)